# unknown keyword present between function return type and name

Tags: c++, c, function, keyword, return-type

Sorry for posting here, I've searched all over Google and couldn't find anything, but it's mainly due to the fact that (as you can see from the title) I don't really know how to call the thing I'm looking for. If I'd know what I'm searching for, I would have already found it elsewhere :) Basically, sometimes I see a macro definition being used between a function's name and return type, that looks very weird, like '__something_', it's not a modifier (const, static, virtual, etc.), it looks like a C compiler macro, but I'm very interested in what they are, as I find them a lot in my code at work. Example:

```
int __whatisthis_ callMe();
```

Personally, I never knew you could actually have another keyword between the function's name and return type, with the exception of common ones like const, static, virtual, etc.. Anyone knows what they are? Thanks!!!

Comment: Suppose you give an actual example.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: Is there any space between `__whatisthis__` and `callMe()`?

Comment: Names starting with a double underscore are reserved for implementation specific use. So it's likely some compiler extension specifying a property of the function, perhaps the way the parameters are passed.

Comment: yes, unfortunately I'm not at work and I couldn't remember the exact form they had, BUT since you're all life savers and yes, I now see they're called "calling conventions", I've managed to find tons of articles on them! :) Thank you so much! I'll link one of the many good tutorials on this subject down below, in case someone might need it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1388/Calling-Conventions-Demystified

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that you can put in between the return type and the name of the function in standard c++. If the specifier does begin with two underscores, then that specifier is implementation specific. The manual of the compiler that you use should explain the meaning of the specifier.